# AP Probability problem on independence

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a in-class practice problem.

Suppose that the probability that a person has to park illegally and that he gets a parking ticket is 0.07. Last year Sam recorded data and found that because of his perpetual tardiness, the probability that he will have to park illegally is 0.25. If Sam arrived late once again this morning and had to park illegally, can you find the probability that Sam will get a parking ticket? If not, what additional information you need to find it?

Here is my thoughts:
A = park illegally
B = get a ticket
A and B are joint, so we could not make sure if they are independent or not.
And we can't find the probability without knowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We're given that:

- $P(A \cap B) = 0.07$
- $P(A) = 0.25$

We're asked to find:

- $P(B \mid A)$

We have enough information to compute this probability; just use the standard formula for conditional probability.

Comment: The result is 0.28, but only if A and B are dependent right? If they're independent, then we could use the formula $ P(B \mid A) = P(B) $. But in that case we don't know $ P(B) $.

Comment: The result will still be $0.28$, even if they're independent, since:
$$
P(B \mid A) = P(B) = \frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{0.07}{0.25} = 0.28
$$

Comment: @Adriano It's just: $P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$, by the definition of conditional probability.  The middle two steps above are wrong.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't think so. For independent events, $ P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B) $

Comment: @shidangai these events are not independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, but if you read my comment to Adriano...I was asking him what if they are independent.